# how to use php set_error_handler for undefined indexes in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a single function for set_error_handler() to deal with undefined indexes in an array with a specific name. For instance, the array is called: $products.
If I have

```
$products = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b' // etc...
```

and later execute call:

```
$a = $products[0];
```

I get an error. I want to handle the error only for the array with the name $products and no other.
How can I make that?

Please don't give me alternatives to this method of solving the problem. I already had a discussion about that and it was decided that it really is better to use this method. I must also warn that this is a super simplification of the real thing.
I have already tried doing some research and nothing helped.

Comment: Instead of an error handler, why don't you just use the [`ArrayAccess` SPL Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php)? Just saying, because the error handler is not able to tell you that it's about a specific variable. Maybe you should share more of your problem that you actually hide?

Comment: Undefined indexes are by default notices, not errors.

Comment: Noone told me about the ArrayAccess interface. I'll take a nice look at it and then report back. Expect report back tomorrow

Comment: I checked and tested it. The ArrayAccess interface is actually the best option for this specific case. I wonder why noone remembered that when I questioned which method was best for this kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up the error handler is easy enough - examples [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) - but filtering based on the code which actually triggered the error just isn't achievable without some very messy regex matching (or something similar) against the error message string.

You're probably going to have to look at some other form of solution if you really require this functionality. You could use `isset()` to check index validity beforehand, or create an array-style class (e.g. using `ArrayAccess` or `ArrayObject` from the SPL) with some index-checking logic built-in.

I know you didn't want different solutions, but I'd be interested to find out why/how you decided that the method you're proposing really is the best way?

Comment: I suppose this is the best way. It's not exactly what I wanted but, at least, it can do the job. Now I need to check how to make this efficient enough to be called 500-700 times in a script.